# add stars to google search result, no wordpress, html css only

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How do I create rating stars using html and css only?

I'm creating a blog from scratch. I want to use that wordpress function to add stars to the google results.

How do I get this by using html and css only? (I'm not using wordpress)

**UPDATE**

Should I add this code, and It will appear in googe search results?

```
  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
 <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Restaurant">
<img itemprop="image" src="seafood-restaurant.jpg" alt="Catcher in the Rye"/>
<span itemprop="name">Legal Seafood</span>
 </div>
 <span itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
<span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span>
 </span> stars -
<b>"<span itemprop="name">A good seafood place.</span>" </b>
<span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
<span itemprop="name">Bob Smith</span>
 </span>
    <span itemprop="reviewBody">The seafood is great.</span>
    <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
     <meta itemprop="name" content="Washington Times">
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: And the duplicate's answer merely links to the [**official documentation**](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review) anyway, which documents the steps very clearly.

Comment: I barely understand. So in other words, if I embbed the code above, it will work?

Comment: Too broad for me, can't understand,